# Mariadb max Error while sending QUERY packet PID

Tags: php, warnings, mariadb

`Mariadb10` with `centos7`

Getting PHP warning in interval while execute backend script.

PHP Warning:  `Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=xxx`

That happen when connection is idle and query fire after time_wait limit
at that time just that warning generate.